# Identifying model with correlograms

Tags: time-series, modeling

i'm struggling finding the right orders of this model. This is a lag=4 seasonally and regularly differenced series(italy trimester exportations), can you help me with it? These are the correlograms. I tried with a (0,0,1)x(0,0,1) and it fitted but i'm not sure. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is an $ARIMA(p=1,d=4,q=1)$ process because:

- $p=1$ because the ACF decays after lag 1
- $d=4$ because you have differenced 4 times
- $q=1$ because the PACF decays after lag 1

Comment: Thanks, but i get the best output just considering the MA and SMA. If i try a (1,0,1)(1,0,1) it gives me the AR parameter non significant and an higher AIC, but i can't understand why. auto.arima also gives me the MA1,SMA1 model

Comment: sorry but i don't get one thing, to find the p,q order i have to look at the lag, but i have to "count" the spikes or i refer to the correlogram lag? i.e for trimester data i got 4 spikes every year, so if the lag 1 is significant the order is 1 or 4? I hope you understand, my english when it comes to explain is very bad... thank you